# Why do we pop off the column?

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression

**Hi!** I wonder why we pop off the 'survived' column in this code example from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/linear

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because it is the label.

Comment: You don't want to pass your labels as a learnable feature because the model would (in theory) just have to learn the labels, and where they're located, and poof, the model has matching features to labels. You also don't pass the label on prediction because then what exactly are you predicting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **feature** is an input to the model; a **label** is the output from the model.

- In your input data, a feature is one column of data.
- [This](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/linear) model is attempting to predict whether or not someone has survived; your input features could include 'class', 'deck', 'embark town', 'alone', and so on.
- The last option is a label, such as 'survived' and thus the 'survived' column is removed.

After you've trained your model, you'll feed it new data with those features, and it'll return the predicted "label" 0(not survived) or 1(survived) for that person.